# change text styles of labels in tabs

Tags: flutter

This looks straight forward enough. I'm trying to change textstyles for my tab labels. Here is my tab widget

```
TabBar(

                unselectedLabelStyle:  TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0,color: Colors.red),
                labelStyle:  TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0,color: Colors.red),
                tabs: [
                  if (venue.availableService.supportsChat)Text('chat'),
                  if (venue.availableService.supportsTableService) Text('Table'),
                  if (venue.availableService.supportsCollection) Text('Collection'),
                  if (venue.availableService.supportsDelivery) Text('Delivery'),
                ],
                controller: tabController,
              ),
```

How do I hook up the labels to the Text widget?

EDIT:
Should probably use the tab widget: `Tab(text:chat)`

But still not getting the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Tab(
      child: Text(
        'Top Rated',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: kFontFamily,
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          //color: Color(0xFF818181),
          //color: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Text(
        'Newest',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontFamily: kFontFamily,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          //color: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    )];
```

Then for more styling in `TabBar()` :

```
TabBar(
     isScrollable: true,
     labelColor: Colors.white,
     unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
     controller: _controller,
     indicatorColor: kAccentColor,
     physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
     indicator: BoxDecoration(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
       color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 87, 157, 1),
     ),
     tabs: myTabs,
),
```